# Bash arithmetic expansion behaviour with empty variables

Tags: bash

I have trouble understanding how bash arithmetic expansion works in some specific cases:

- variable is unset or empty
- operation involves another operator than + or -
- a dollar is used to expand variable

When all these requirements are met I get the error:

> syntax error: operand expected (error token is ...

Here are some examples :

```bash
unset var   # or var=''
unset value

echo $(($var * 2)) # error
echo $(($var + 2)) # no error
echo $((var * 2))  # no error

var='value'
echo $(($var * 2)) # no error
```

Why is var not replaced by a 0 in the first statement like in all the other ones?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Expansion of parameter names in arithmetic context has special properties. For example, parameter names are resolved until we find a numeric value:

```
$ var1=5
$ var2=var1
$ echo $(( var2 ))
5
```

If the chain ends, for example if `var1` isn't defined in above example, the result is zero:

```
$ unset var1
$ echo $(( var2 ))
0
```

Using the parameter name directly also expands to zero:

```
$ echo $(( var1 ))
0
```

Even nothing expands to zero:

```
$ echo $(( ))
0
```

But there is a difference between using `$var` and just `var`:

```
$ unset var
$ echo $(( var * 1 ))
0
$ echo $(( $var * 1 ))
-bash: * 1 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is "* 1 ")
```

The first one expands to `0 * 1`, but the second one to  `* 1`, which is a syntax error because `*` requires two operands. This is your first example.

Your second example expands to  `+ 2`, which is fine: `+` is interpreted as unary plus. It's not replaced by a zero, as you assume in your question.

The third and fourth one both expand to `0 * 2`, as shown above: non-integer values like `value` are interpreted as zero in arithmetic context.

Comment: Thanks makes sense, but this made me wonder : is there any interest in keeping the dollar when referring to a simple variable (apart from avoiding bugs by detecting that the variable is empty) ?

Comment: @QuentinL'Hours: there's rarely any need to use `$` in math contexts, such is within `$(( ))`. In other contexts, it's generally required. For example, `if [ var -lt 10 ]` will give you an error ("integer expression expected"), but `if [ "$var" -lt 10 ]` will work (provided `$var` expands to a valid integer).

Comment: @QuentinL'Hours In arithmetic context, I always skip the `$` as notation without it is much more convenient.